# How can click enter through selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I want to automate video uploading to asite. There is a textbox to enter tags there. So I want to paste my tags to that textbox and then click enter!
I used this code for click on 'Enter':

```
youporn.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='token-input-']")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

But I am getting an error:
[image: Image of error]

Comment: import `OpenQA.Selenium.Keys` or replace `SendKeys(Keys.Enter)` with `SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter)`

Comment: If you read the error message on the screen and google it, you probably could have found the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know if you mean the `Keys` enum of `System.Windows.Forms` or `OpenQA.Selenium`. Change it to the following and your stuff works.

```
youporn.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='token-input-']")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```